# Haskell function application and currying

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, currying

I am always interested in learning new languages, a fact that keeps me on my toes and makes me (I believe) a better programmer. My attempts at conquering Haskell come and go - twice so far - and I decided it was time to try again. 3rd time's the charm, right?

Nope. I re-read my old notes... and get disappointed :-(

The problem that made me lose faith last time, was an easy one: permutations of integers.
i.e. from a list of integers, to a list of lists - a list of their permutations:

```
[int] -> [[int]]
```

This is in fact a generic problem, so replacing 'int' above with 'a', would still apply.

From my notes:

I code it first on my own, I succeed. Hurrah!

I send my solution to a good friend of mine - Haskell guru, it usually helps to learn from gurus - and he sends me this, which I am told, "expresses the true power of the language, the use of generic facilities to code your needs". All for it, I recently drank the kool-aid, let's go:

```
permute :: [a] -> [[a]]
permute = foldr (concatMap.ins) [[]]
   where ins x []     = [[x]]
         ins x (y:ys) = (x:y:ys):[ y:res | res <- ins x ys]
```

Hmm.
Let's break this down:

```
bash$ cat b.hs
ins x []     = [[x]]
ins x (y:ys) = (x:y:ys):[ y:res | res <- ins x ys]

bash$ ghci
Prelude> :load b.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( b.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.

*Main> ins 1 [2,3]
[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]]
```

OK, so far, so good. Took me a minute to understand the second line of "ins", but OK:
It places the 1st arg in all possible positions in the list. Cool.

Now, to understand the foldr and concatMap. in "Real world Haskell", the DOT was explained...

```
(f . g) x
```

...as just another syntax for...

```
f (g x)
```

And in the code the guru sent, DOT was used from a foldr, with the "ins" function as the fold "collapse":

```
*Main> let g=concatMap . ins
*Main> g 1 [[2,3]]
[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]]
```

OK, since I want to understand how the DOT is used by the guru, I try the equivalent expression according to the DOT definition, (f . g) x = f (g x) ...

```
*Main> concatMap (ins 1 [[2,3]])

<interactive>:1:11:
     Couldn't match expected type `a -> [b]'
            against inferred type `[[[t]]]'
     In the first argument of `concatMap', namely `(ins 1 [[2, 3]])'
     In the expression: concatMap (ins 1 [[2, 3]])
     In the definition of `it': it = concatMap (ins 1 [[2, 3]])
```

What!?! Why?
OK, I check concatMap's signature, and find that it needs a lambda and a list, but that's 
just a human thinking; how does GHC cope? According to the definition of DOT above...

```
(f.g)x = f(g x),
```

...what I did was valid, replace-wise:

```
(concatMap . ins) x y = concatMap (ins x y)
```

Scratching head...

```
*Main> concatMap (ins 1) [[2,3]]
[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]]
```

So... The DOT explanation was apparently
too simplistic... DOT must be somehow clever enough to understand
that we in fact wanted "ins" to get curri-ed away and "eat" the first
argument - thus becoming a function that only wants to operate on [t]
(and "intersperse" them with '1' in all possible positions).

But where was this specified? How did GHC knew to do this, when we invoked:

```
*Main> (concatMap . ins) 1 [[2,3]]
[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]]
```

Did the "ins" signature somehow conveyed this... "eat my first argument" policy?

```
*Main> :info ins
ins :: t -> [t] -> [[t]]        -- Defined at b.hs:1:0-2
```

I don't see nothing special - "ins" is a function that takes a 't', 
a list of 't', and proceeds to create a list with all "interspersals". Nothing about "eat your first argument and curry it away".

So there... I am baffled. I understand (after an hour of looking at the code!) what goes on, but... God almighty... Perhaps GHC makes attempts to see how many arguments it can "peel off"?

```
  let's try with no argument "curried" into "ins",
  oh gosh, boom, 
  let's try with one argument "curried" into "ins",
  yep, works,
  that must be it, proceed)
```

Again - yikes...

And since I am always comparing the languages I am learning with what I already know, how would "ins" look in Python?

```
a=[2,3]
print [a[:x]+[1]+a[x:] for x in xrange(len(a)+1)]

[[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1]]
```

Be honest, now... which is simpler?

I mean, I know I am a newbie in Haskell, but I feel like an idiot... Looking at 4 lines of code for an hour, and ending up assuming that the compiler... tries various interpretations until it finds something that "clicks"?

To quote from Lethal weapon, "I am too old for this"...

Comment: You may want to add a TLDR section for the lazy...

Comment: I don't understand Haskell, but boy do I agree with what you said. +1.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your python comparison. The python code you showed is just for the `ins` function, right? But the `ins` function wasn't what you found complicated in the Haskell version - the concatMap was and that's the part you left out in your python version.

Comment: I don't understand Hasakell either...but, if the primary goal of software is to reduce complexity...then this seems a battle. Why are all the variable names only one letter long?

Comment: @sepp2k: In the end, frustrated, I simply compare the complexity of "ins" in Python and Haskell, and find the Python version to be idiot-proof. Nothing more than that.

Comment: @tts: Btw, the Haskell equivalent of your python code is `[take x a ++ [1] ++ drop x a | x <- [0..length(a)]]`, though this is less efficient than what your friend gave you.

Comment: To be fair, my Python is a bit rusty these days, but... your friend's `ins` seems much simpler to me than your Python version (or @sepp2k's Haskell equivalent, for that matter). I mean, computing the length of the list and splitting it up by index? Isn't that... kind of awkward and obfuscated? Not to mention that your friend's `ins` is lazy, and works on infinite lists...

Comment: When the blind lead the blind, you run into a lot of walls.

Comment: Also, is it just me, or is Stack Overflow getting more inane?  Has reading stupid questions about how Haskell is too hard killed the part of people's brains that tells them that their inane 
"questions" belong on a blag or on #leet on irc?

Comment: Discussion is great, but, from the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): "Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion.  This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!" [Where can I find interesting programming discussions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions)  This would be a great first post for a new blog.

Comment: You probably did not know, that **ins :: t -> [t] -> [[t]]** equals **ins :: t -> ([t] -> [[t]])**. You might want to examine the functions **curry** and **uncurry**.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

This is true. You concluded from that that

```
(f . g) x y = f (g x y)
```

must also be true, but that is not the case. In fact, the following is true:

```
(f . g) x y = f (g x) y
```

which is not the same.

Why is this true? Well `(f . g) x y` is the same as `((f . g) x) y` and since we know that `(f . g) x = f (g x)` we can reduce that to `(f (g x)) y`, which is again the same as `f (g x) y`.

So `(concatMap . ins) 1 [[2,3]]` is equivalent to `concatMap (ins 1) [[2,3]]`. There is no magic going on here.

Another way to approach this is via the types:

`.` has the type `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`, `concatMap` has the type `(x -> [y]) -> [x] -> [y]`, `ins` has the type `t -> [t] -> [[t]]`. So if we use `concatMap` as the `b -> c` argument and `ins` as the `a -> b` argument, then `a` becomes `t`, `b` becomes `[t] -> [[t]]` and `c` becomes `[[t]] -> [[t]]` (with `x` = `[t]` and `y` = `[t]`).

So the type of `concatMap . ins` is `t -> [[t]] -> [[t]]`, which means a function taking a whatever and a list of lists (of whatevers) and returning a list of lists (of the same type).

Comment: Oh how I wish the guru had responded the way you did. I asked him, of course - and he confirmed that Haskell indeed tried combinations to see what works! ... OK, you win, here I go for the 3rd time, diving in... (next time, btw, I'll ask Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: Haskell doesn't "try combinations", it mechanically follows the definition.  What is the definition?  You can use hoogle and haddock to find the source really fast: `(.) f g x = f (g x)`.  So yes, just ONE argument.

Comment: @TomMD: Me a newbie: what do you mean, about Hoogle, exactly? I found it, typed the expression in, an error came up. Elaborate?

Comment: @tts: If you enter `.` into hoogle you get a list of functions named `.`. If you click the first result, you'll get to the docs for the standard (prelude) `.` function. If you click the "source" link there, you'll see the definition of `.` in the standard library, which is `(.) f g x = f (g x)` (which is just another way of writing `(f . g) x = f (g x)`).

Comment: @ttsiodras: As sepp2k said, search for [(.)](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28.%29), click on the [search hit](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v:.), click on where the haddock documentation says [source](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/src/GHC-Base.html#.).

Comment: @ttsiodras: I have to say, either there was some sort of miscommunication when you asked him, or your friend isn't really much of a "Haskell guru"...

Comment: @sepp2k:  one small error in your last paragraph: the type of concatMap is `t -> [[t]] -> [[t]]` .  Otherwise, very nice explanation.

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to add my two cents. The question and answer make it sound like `.` is some magical operator that does strange things with re-arranging function calls. That's not the case. `.` is just function composition. Here's an implementation in Python:

```
def dot(f, g):
    def result(arg):
        return f(g(arg))
    return result
```

It just creates a new function which applies `g` to an argument, applies `f` to the result, and returns the result of applying `f`.

So `(concatMap . ins) 1 [[2, 3]]` is saying: create a function, `concatMap . ins`, and apply it to the arguments `1` and `[[2, 3]]`. When you do `concatMap (ins 1 [[2,3]])` you're instead saying, apply the function `concatMap` to the result of applying `ins` to `1` and `[[2, 3]]` - completely different, as you figured out by Haskell's horrendous error message.

UPDATE: To stress this even further. You said that `(f . g) x` was another syntax for `f (g x)`. This is **wrong**! `.` is just a function, as functions can have non-alpha-numeric names (`>><`, `..`, etc., could also be function names).

Comment: I don't think this would work the same way in python do to lack of currying.

Comment: you're right, I think.. i'm assuming one-arg functions for the composition. you will have to convert multi-arg funcs into funcs that take one argument and return other funcs to get the curry effect

Comment: For what it's worth, `..` is an invalid identifer in Haskell (special syntax).

Comment: @trinithis: However, `(...)` is valid, as are `(--:)`, `(:::)`, `(<--)`, `(@.@)`, and various other names containing special syntax as a substring.

Comment: +1 for the operators-are-just-functions. It is so natural for me that operators are functions that I didn't realized that he thought that `.` was a special form.

Answer (score 5):

You're overthinking this problem.  You can work it all out using simple equational reasoning.  Let's try it from scratch:

```
permute = foldr (concatMap . ins) [[]]
```

This can be converted trivially to:

```
permute lst = foldr (concatMap . ins) [[]] lst
```

`concatMap` can be defined as:

```
concatMap f lst = concat (map f lst)
```

The way `foldr` works on a list is that (for instance):

```
-- let lst = [x, y, z]
foldr f init lst
= foldr f init [x, y, z]
= foldr f init (x : y : z : [])
= f x (f y (f z init))
```

So something like

```
permute [1, 2, 3]
```

becomes:

```
foldr (concatMap . ins) [[]] [1, 2, 3]
= (concatMap . ins) 1 
    ((concatMap . ins) 2
       ((concatMap . ins) 3 [[]]))
```

Let's work through the first expression:

```
(concatMap . ins) 3 [[]]
= (\x -> concatMap (ins x)) 3 [[]]  -- definition of (.)
= (concatMap (ins 3)) [[]]
= concatMap (ins 3) [[]]     -- parens are unnecessary
= concat (map (ins 3) [[]])  -- definition of concatMap
```

Now `ins 3 [] == [3]`, so

```
map (ins 3) [[]] == (ins 3 []) : []  -- definition of map
= [3] : []
= [[3]]
```

So our original expression becomes:

```
foldr (concatMap . ins) [[]] [1, 2, 3]
= (concatMap . ins) 1 
    ((concatMap . ins) 2
       ((concatMap . ins) 3 [[]]))
= (concatMap . ins) 1 
    ((concatMap . ins) 2 [[3]]
```

Let's work through

```
(concatMap . ins) 2 [[3]]
= (\x -> concatMap (ins x)) 2 [[3]]
= (concatMap (ins 2)) [[3]]
= concatMap (ins 2) [[3]]     -- parens are unnecessary
= concat (map (ins 2) [[3]])  -- definition of concatMap
= concat (ins 2 [3] : [])
= concat ([[2, 3], [3, 2]] : [])
= concat [[[2, 3], [3, 2]]]
= [[2, 3], [3, 2]]
```

So our original expression becomes:

```
foldr (concatMap . ins) [[]] [1, 2, 3]
= (concatMap . ins) 1 [[2, 3], [3, 2]]
= (\x -> concatMap (ins x)) 1 [[2, 3], [3, 2]]
= concatMap (ins 1) [[2, 3], [3, 2]]
= concat (map (ins 1) [[2, 3], [3, 2]])
= concat [ins 1 [2, 3], ins 1 [3, 2]] -- definition of map
= concat [[[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1]], 
          [[1, 3, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]]  -- defn of ins
= [[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], 
   [1, 3, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Nothing magical here.  I think you may have been confused because it's easy to  assume that `concatMap = concat . map`, but this is not the case.   Similarly, it may seem like `concatMap f = concat . (map f)`, but this isn't true either. Equational reasoning will show you why.