# Trying to improve a current ugly piece of code in haskell dealing with lists

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to implement a function in Haskell that'll take an arbitrary integer list `xs` and an integer `k`, and returns a set of lists with `k` in all possible positions.

For example, for a `xs = [0, 1]` and `k = 2`, we'd have

```
myFunction [0, 1] 2 = [ [2, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 2] ]
```

I've implemented it as

```
putOn xs x i = (take i xs) ++ (x:(drop i xs))
putOnAll xs x = map (putOn xs x) [0..(length xs)]
```

yet, I feel there must be other smarter ways to achieve the same. My code seems like someone trying to kill a bug with a missile. Could anyone make sugestions on ways to do something clever than this bit of code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884121/haskell-i-am-too-old-for-this/3884182#3884182):

```
ins x []     = [[x]]
ins x (y:ys) = (x:y:ys):[ y:res | res <- ins x ys]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use arrows, too:

```
import Control.Arrow

ins x = inits &&& tails >>> second (map (x:)) >>> uncurry (zipWith (++))
```

With `&&&` ("fanout") you give one argument to two functions, which gives a pair of results. You can use `>>>` ("and then") to switch the normal application order, allowing to have left-to-right chains of operations. `second` works only on the second part of the pair. Finally you need an `uncurry` to recombine the results, feeding a pair in a function expecting two separate arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the clarity of this definition:

```
ins x ys = zipWith (\pre post -> pre ++ [x] ++ post) (inits ys) (tails ys)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ins x xs = zipWith (\ a b -> a ++ (x:b)) (inits xs) (tails xs)
```

[Edit] Bah, too late, luqui beat me :-)

However, here a version without lambda:

```
ins x xs = zipWith (flip (++).(:) x) (tails xs) (inits xs)
```